# Doxygen: documenting class in .dox file

Tags: doxygen

The \class command can be used to put the documentation for a class into a .dox file -- see http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdclass . (For those of us who find Javadocs-style documentation makes header files nigh unreadable.)

How do you move documentation for the class's methods into a .dox file too?

To give an example, if I have a Datatypes.h

```
struct Coordinates {
    const double lat;
    const double lng;

    Coordinates(double lat, double lng);
};
```

And then I create Datatypes.dox

```
/** \class Coordinates
 * \brief Represents (latitude, longitude) coordinates encoded according to the World Geodetic System (WGS84).
 */

/* \var const double Coordinates::lat
 * \brief the latitude
 */
```

then Coordinates is picked up in the index, but Coordinates::lat isn't. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Please give some more information of what you want (i.e. a small example + indication of the output). Looks a bit like that you want to use `\copydoc` but it is not clear from your question. Please also specify your doxygen version.

Comment: @albert see above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code of Datatypes.dox we see:

```
/* \var const double Coordinates::lat
 * \brief the latitude
 */
```

This is not a doxygen understood comment, but a regular comment. The comment should be (note the second `*` in the first line):

```
/** \var const double Coordinates::lat
 * \brief the latitude
 */
```

Alternatively you could join the both documentation sections to:

```
/** \class Coordinates
 * \brief Represents (latitude, longitude) coordinates encoded according to the World Geodetic System (WGS84).
 *
 * \var const double Coordinates::lat
 * \brief the latitude
 */
```

Comment: D'oh. ... But still not right; I get 'warning: documented symbol `const double Coordinates::lat' was not declared or defined.'

Comment: Strange I get only (as expected): `.../Datatypes.h:6: warning: Member Coordinates(double lat, double lng) (function) of class Coordinates is not documented.`
`.../Datatypes.h:4: warning: Member lng (variable) of class Coordinates is not documented.`   Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you try the code you typed in this question, just cut and paste back to be sure that there are no other typos (a wild goose chase).

Comment: Probably found the issue, are you sure that the `Datatypes.h` is read as when I remove the `Datatypes.h` I get the mentioned warning.

Comment: That was it -- I had written `FILE_PATTERNS = *.h, *.dox` and doxygen doesn't like the comma. Thank you very much!